# how to update label in swift using SWITCH and a uiTextfield variable

Tags: ios, swift, switch-statement, case

I want to make a small program where when a person types "happy" or "sad" in the text field, the label updates based on the case and says something... here is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var aiAnswer: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var humanResponse: UITextField!

    // when user taps submit run this

    @IBAction func responseRequest(sender: AnyObject) {

    // check the variable humanResponse to see if they typed happy or sad and update the UI label based on that

        switch (humanResponse) {

        case "happy":

                aiAnswer.text = "thats great your happy!";

        case "sad":

                aiAnswer.text = "thats no fun!";

        default:

                aiAnswer.text = "please input a valid emotions";




        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with your `switch` case. Update it like this:

```
switch humanResponse.text! {   //text entered by user

    case "happy":

        aiAnswer.text = "thats great your happy!";

    case "sad":

        aiAnswer.text = "thats no fun!";

    default:

        aiAnswer.text = "please input a valid emotions";

    }
```